# How is `gdb` attaching to running processes?

Tags: c, gdb, ptrace

I want to create a simple tool (with C) which can do this tiny subset of `gdb`s features:

1. Attach to an already running program (with PID)
2. Inject instructions into it like this:

> dup2(open("/tmp/my_stdout", 1089, 0777), 1)

GDB can do this without issues, but it has a massive source.

What Im looking for is some kind of starting point of guidance.

There are tons of information on Google but all of them are 10ish years old, and I need to make this work on aarch64 arch which was not existed by that time.

Really, any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to *strace* gdb while it is attaching to a process, but my terminal blowed up literally.

Comment: You've tagged `ptrace` so clearly you have some idea that that is what is needed. Have you read the [ptrace manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) and searched for examples. After that you should try some code and narrow down what specifically about using `ptrace` you have issue with.

Comment: @kaylum: I couldn't reach too far, can you please check two related questions of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076261/how-can-i-use-ptrace-pokeuser-to-fill-parameters-of-nr-mmap-on-an-attached-p

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076404/how-can-i-inject-code-to-attached-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im looking for is some kind of starting point of guidance.

Take a look at the unwind-pid example [here](https://github.com/daniel-thompson/libunwind-examples). It uses ptrace to unwind the stack of an alien process, identified by PID.

Note: you could ignore all the `unw_*` calls. The "attach to pid" part is rather trivial:

```
    pid_t pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0) != 0)
        die("ERROR: cannot attach to %d\n", pid);
...
    (void) ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);
```

> Inject instructions into it like this: `dup2(open("/tmp/my_stdout", 1089, 0777), 1)`

Search for "Linux inject code into running process". Here is one [example](https://0x00sec.org/t/linux-infecting-running-processes/1097).

**Update:**

> That will not work, I think. I don't want to dup2 the tracer's stdout. I want to dup2 the tracee's stdout!

Yes you do, and yes it will.

Well, maybe not quite (you *could* do it with code injection, but you don't *have* to).

What you want to do is construct (on the stack and in registers) the state of the tracee *as if* it just called `open("/tmp/my_stdout", ...)` itself. Then set a breakpoint after `open` returns, set `IP` to `open` and resume the tracee. The tracee will run until the breakpoint, at which point you will have an open `fd` in the results register. Now repeat the same process for `dup2`, and you are done.

Comment: Attachment is done. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: That will *not* work, I think. I don't want to dup2 the tracer's stdout. I want to dup2 the *tracee*'s stdout! For that tracee has to open the `/tmp/my_stdout` and tracee has to call dup2 on that opened FD.

Comment: "That will not work ..." -- yes it will. I've updated the answer again.